# Google Map Drawmap Doesnt Download the full Drawing using Javascript, PHP

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

I am using google map javascript to draw any shape, on the map and then download the drawing portion using the downloadmap javascript function. Everything works perfectly but the problem is the drawn portion is incomplete, example below, it should join all the corners but it does not. It happens with almost any shape that I create.

[image]

```js
 var map;
    var drawingManager;
    var selectedShape;
    var shapes = [];

    function initMap() {
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {lat: 0, lng: 0},
        zoom: 2
      });

      drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
        drawingControlOptions: {
          position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
          drawingModes: ['polygon']
        }
      });

      drawingManager.setMap(map);

      google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function(e) {
        if (e.type != google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER) {
          // Switch back to non-drawing mode after drawing is complete
          drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null);

          // Add shape to the array of shapes
          var newShape = e.overlay;
          newShape.type = e.type;
          shapes.push(newShape);

          // Set selected shape
          selectedShape = newShape;

          // Calculate area of the shape
          var area = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeArea(selectedShape.getPath());
          $('#area').text('Area: ' + area.toFixed(2) + ' sq m');

          // Add event listeners to the shape
          google.maps.event.addListener(newShape, 'click', function() {
            setSelection(newShape);
          });
          setSelection(newShape);
        }
      });

      // Set up event listeners on the clear button
      $('#clear').click(function() {
        clearSelection();
        clearShapes();
        $('#area').text('');
      });

      // Set up event listeners on the download button
      $('#download').click(function() {
        downloadMap();
      });

      // Wait for map to be fully loaded before triggering downloadMap function
      google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function() {
        downloadMap();
      });
    }

    function setSelection(shape) {
      clearSelection();
      selectedShape = shape;
      selectedShape.setEditable(true);
    }

    function clearSelection() {
      if (selectedShape) {
        selectedShape.setEditable(false);
        selectedShape = null;
      }
    }

    function clearShapes() {
      for (var i = 0; i < shapes.length; i++) {
        shapes[i].setMap(null);
      }
      shapes = [];
    }

function downloadMap() {
  var center = map.getCenter();
  var zoom = map.getZoom();
  var scale = 2;
  var size = map.getDiv().clientWidth + 'x' + map.getDiv().clientHeight;
  var mapTypeId = map.getMapTypeId();

 var url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?key=KEY&center=' + center.lat() + ',' + center.lng() + '&zoom=' + zoom + '&size=' + size + '&scale=' + scale + '&maptype=' + mapTypeId;

  // Add polygons to the URL
  for (var i = 0; i < shapes.length; i++) {
    if (shapes[i].type === google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON) {
      var path = shapes[i].getPath();
      var polygons = [];

      for (var j = 0; j < path.getLength(); j++) {
        polygons.push(path.getAt(j).toUrlValue());
      }

      if (polygons.length > 0) {
        url += '&path=' + polygons.join('|');
      }
    }
  }

  fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.blob())
    .then(blob => {
      const form = new FormData();
      form.append('image', blob, 'map.png');

      // Send image data to server to save it
      fetch('save_map.php', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: form
      })
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(result => console.log(result))
      .catch(error => console.error(error));
    })
    .catch(error => console.error(error));
}
```

```css
    html, body {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    #map {
      height: 100%;
    }
```

```html
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap&libraries=drawing"

<div id="map"></div>
  <div id="area"></div>
  <button id="clear">Clear</button>
  <button id="download">Download</button>
```

My PHP code for `save_map.php` is here

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
  $image = $_FILES['image'];
  $directory = 'maps';
  if (!file_exists($directory)) {
    mkdir($directory, 0777, true);
  }
  $filename = $directory . '/map_' . time() . '.png';

  if (move_uploaded_file($image['tmp_name'], $filename)) {
    echo 'Map saved successfully.';
  } else {
    echo 'Error saving map.';
  }
} else {
  echo 'Invalid request.';
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Polygon is not being closed when you try to export as an image perhaps what you need to do is add the 1st location clicked at the end of the array once you have iterated through the entire points collection.

So, when you are building the url modify this:

```
  for (var i = 0; i < shapes.length; i++) {
    if (shapes[i].type === google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON) {
      var path = shapes[i].getPath();
      var polygons = [];

      for (var j = 0; j < path.getLength(); j++) {
        polygons.push(path.getAt(j).toUrlValue());
      }

      if (polygons.length > 0) {
        url += '&path=' + polygons.join('|');
      }
    }
  }
```

to this

```
// Add polygons to the URL
for( var i = 0; i < shapes.length; i++ ) {
    if( shapes[i].type === google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON ) {
        var path = shapes[i].getPath();
        var polygons = [];

        for( var j = 0; j < path.getLength(); j++ ) {
            polygons.push(path.getAt(j).toUrlValue());
        }

        // add the 1st location to the end of the polygons array
        polygons.push( shapes[0].getPath().getAt(0).toUrlValue() );

        if( polygons.length > 0 ) {
            url += '&path=' + polygons.join('|');
        }
    }
}
```